# Can't find Huggingface npm packages for node.js?

Tags: node.js, huggingface, distilbert

I am trying to execute a code in node.js using DistilBERT and need to install the below dependencies. They don't seem to work. Anyone knows?

npm install @huggingface/transformers
npm install @huggingface/tokenizers

Comment: are you sure there are npm packages for this?

Comment: apparently not.